# How to replace url in js whihot jquery?

Tags: javascript

Guys i have many links:

"img/dasda/ja.png", "../img/no.png", "wild/rpm/gulp/in.png",

How in js change sting to last "/"? To get just the name of image?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "img/dasda/ja.png";

var idx = url.lastIndexOf('/');
console.log(url.substring(idx + 1));
```

Comment: thanks, thats work

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#match` together with `RegExp`.

```js
var links = ["img/dasda/ja.png", "../img/no.png", "wild/rpm/gulp/in.png"];

links.forEach(v => console.log(v.match(/(?!\/)\w+(?=\.)/g)[0]));
```